# Implementation: How to retrieve and send emails for different Gmail accounts?

Tags: php, python, email, gmail

I need advice and how to got about setting up a simple service for my users. I would like to add a new feature where users can send and receive emails from their gmail account. I have seen this done several times and I know its possible.

There use to be a project for "Libgmailer" at sourceforge but I think it was abandoned. Is anyone aware of anything similar?

I have found that Gmail has a Python API but my site is making use of PHP.

I really need ideas on how to best go about this!

Thanks all for any input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

any library/source that works with imap or pop will work.

Comment: Like PHPMailer? Also would I have to do what Kevin Laity asked in his Answer?

Comment: Sorry to keep going in circles. You say "that case", does that mean not in your case?

Comment: @abs, when talking about 'case' perhaps he is referring to the fact that pop/imap must be enabled in the users Gmail settings.

Comment: yes, if you are using imap or pop access you need to do what Kevin says - the users need to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if Google didn't come up with anything personally I'd see if I could reverse engineer the Python API by implementing it and watching it with a packet sniffer. My guess is it's just accessing some web service which should be pretty easy to mimic regardless of the language you're using.

Comment: Or you could just use SMTP and IMAP/POP to send/receive email through Gmail.

Comment: Google only allows SSL encrypted SMTP and POP3 which is kind of a pain to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, Gmail supports POP/IMAP access. Could you do it using those protocols? It would mean asking your users to go into their gmail and enable it though.

Comment: Any other way without them having to enable it?

Comment: The only other possibility I think is something that actually pretends to be a browser and parses the html that gmail sends. It would be a risk though, in case they ever do a major revamp of their html.